# Bound for Parabolic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $u$ solve $u_t - \Delta u + u^2 = 0$ on $[0,T] \times\mathbb{R}^d$. Prove that $u(T,x) \leq 1/T$ for all $x$ (regardless of initial conditions).

My attempt:
We see that $u_t - \Delta u = -u^2 \leq 0$ on $\overline{U_T}$. Hence, by the maximum principle, we see that $\max_{\partial pU_T}u = \max_{U_T} u $. How can I use this fact to prove the bound on $u(T,x)$? It seems as if I have too little information about $u$ to do so. I was thinking of constructing some auxiliary function and applying the comparison principle, but it seems that not even this will work.

Comment: Are you sure it's $T^{-1}$and $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: Yes, the bound is $1/T$ and the spatial domain is the full space. Does this break down somehow?

Comment: Are you sure it's dimension $d$?

Comment: Yes. d is not of any significance.

Comment: where did you get the problem from?

Comment: Assigned by my professor for an undergrad pde class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $v(t)=1/t$ satisfies the equation $v_t-\Delta v+v^2=0$. For all $x\in[0,1]$, $\lim_{t\to0^+}v(t)>u(x,0)$. By the comparison principle, $u(x,t)\le v(t)$.

Comment: Bah, it was right in front of my face. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, just came back to this and I don't understand the solution entirely. We have that because $u$ is bounded, for $t_0$ sufficiently small, $v(t) \geq u(x,t)$ for all $t_0$. How can I use this to bound $u(x,T)$?

Comment: The maximum principle compares solutions $u$ and $0$. The comparison principle, which is a generalization of the maximum principle, allows to compare two solutions, and in this case implies that $u\le v$. By the way, I am assuming Dirichlet boundary conditions.